# How to monkeypatch Ruby properly?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, monkeypatching

I'm trying to monkeypatch a line in Net class in the standard library. I created a file called patches.rb into the lib folder of the project and added this

```
module Net
  class HTTP < Protocol
    module HTTPHeader
      def initialize_http_header(initheader)
        @header = {}
        return unless initheader
        initheader.each do |key, value|
          @header[key.downcase] = [value.strip] rescue ""
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work. Am I doing this right? (That parallels the inheritance hierarchy exactly.)

Edit: part of the problem was I had to put the file in the initalizers folder. But still seeing the same error.

Comment: are you then doing `require 'lib/patches'` ?

Comment: @caley I thought everything in lib folder were loaded automatically at boot up.

Comment: Sorry, it is, I thought you were referring to a lib folder of your creation.

Comment: @taro: the error is a whiny_nil which is a problem I'm trying to rescue from. As long as I see the error, that means my patch is not overriding the original.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since things in the `lib/` directory are only loaded on demand, you may have more success putting patches like this in `config/initializers/` where they are automatically loaded after the stack has been initialized.

You can also collapse the definition for extensions to something like this:

```
module Net::HTTP::HTTPHeader
  # ... (redefined methods) ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, tadman. I collapsed the definition, but executed code still appears to come from the code origin.

Comment: It can be easy to monkeypatch the wrong thing, so you should always double-check the name-space of your target. I had a look in `net/http.rb` and it should probably be `Net::HTTPHeader` you're redefining methods in, not `Net::HTTP::HTTPHeader`.